# Pulp/python function for blending calculator

Tags: python, product, blending, pulp

[Blend image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3uAS.jpg) Was hoping to get some help on this problem as I'm a novice in python.
The problem: we are looking to blend a target beer with certain parameters (Colour, alcohol, etc) and utilize an existing stock of "mother" beers to achieve this (50 percent beer 1, 20 percent beer 2, 30 percent beer 3). I attached an image that hopefully explains better. 
I was having trouble finding a solution to the problem in excel and found this bit of code on the pulp website that seemed to be exactly what I was after.

https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/CaseStudies/a_blending_problem.html

However, we do not need to minimize costs I was hoping to output simply if a solution is possible and what are the percentages needed to achieve it. I did use this method to build my idea up.
I keep getting stuck though. My output seems to default to 100 percent of one beer every time and I cannot get a blend to work, even with combinations I already know the solution to. I assume I am making some simple mistake due to lack of knowledge with pulp but can anyone help point me in the right direction? I see the __dummy added to my list but am not sure why.

```
from pulp import *
Ingredients = ['Beer 1', 'Beer 2', 'Beer 3', 'Beer 4']
RDF = {'Beer 1': 60, 
     'Beer 2': 60, 
     'Beer 3': 70, 
     'Beer 4': 70}
IBU = {'Beer 1': 15, 
     'Beer 2': 40, 
     'Beer 3': 25, 
     'Beer 4': 40}
Colour = {'Beer 1': 6, 
     'Beer 2': 40, 
     'Beer 3': 6, 
     'Beer 4': 15}
prob = LpProblem("BeerTest", LpMinimize)
ingredient_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",Ingredients,0)
prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 100, "PercentagesSum"
prob += lpSum([RDF[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) ==67, "RDF"
prob += lpSum([IBU[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) ==22, "IBU"
prob.writeLP("BlendTest1")
[Ingr_Beer_1, Ingr_Beer_2, Ingr_Beer_3, Ingr_Beer_4, __dummy]
prob.solve()
-1

print ("Status:"), LpStatus[prob.status]
Status:
(None, 'Infeasible')

for v in prob.variables():
print (v.name),"=",v.varValue


    Ingr_Beer_1
(None, '=', 100.0)
Ingr_Beer_2
(None, '=', 0.0)
Ingr_Beer_3
(None, '=', 0.0)
Ingr_Beer_4
(None, '=', 0.0)
__dummy
(None, '=', None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much got this working. Two small problems; you're print statements aren't quite correct (assuming python 3, see below), and also you're multiplying two percentages incorrectly - you need to divide by 100.

With slight changes below for your example I get the following output:

```
Status:Optimal
Ingr_Beer_1=30.0
Ingr_Beer_2=0.0
Ingr_Beer_3=70.0
Ingr_Beer_4=0.0
__dummy=None
```

Using the following code:

```
from pulp import *

Ingredients = ['Beer 1', 'Beer 2', 'Beer 3', 'Beer 4']

RDF = {'Beer 1': 60, 
     'Beer 2': 60, 
     'Beer 3': 70, 
     'Beer 4': 70}

IBU = {'Beer 1': 15, 
     'Beer 2': 40, 
     'Beer 3': 25, 
     'Beer 4': 40}

Colour = {'Beer 1': 6, 
     'Beer 2': 40, 
     'Beer 3': 6, 
     'Beer 4': 15}

prob = LpProblem("BeerTest", LpMinimize)
ingredient_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",Ingredients,0)
prob += lpSum([ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) == 100, "PercentagesSum"
prob += lpSum([RDF[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients])/100 == 67, "RDF"
prob += lpSum([IBU[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients])/100 == 22, "IBU"
prob.writeLP("BlendTest1")

prob.solve()


print ("Status:" + str(LpStatus[prob.status]))

for v in prob.variables():
    print (v.name + "=" + str(v.varValue))
```

As a side note I'd recommend working in fractions [0 - 1.0] rather than percentages [0-100] as it tends to work out neater.